# Build Errors When Importing Wiktionary

Tags: android, wiktionary

When importing the Wiktionary project into Eclipse, I immediately get error messages related to my `strings.xml` file. The same errors occur whether I download the project through subversion or from the SDK sample files.

Console errors:

```
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] W/ResourceType( 2752): Bad XML block: header size 62 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\values\strings.xml:22: error: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\values\strings.xml:22: error: Unexpected end tag string
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\layout\widget_message.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/widget_loading').
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\xml\searchable.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/search_label').
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\xml\searchable.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/search_hint').
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\menu\lookup.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/lookup_search').
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\menu\lookup.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/lookup_random').
[2010-12-27 15:25:33 - Wiktionary] C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\menu\lookup.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/lookup_about').
```

Answer (score 3):

The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) has become very strict in its latest release and is now used for all Android versions. The aapt-error you're getting is generated because it no longer allows non-positional format specifiers.

So you have to make some changes into your C:\Trunk\Wiktionary\res\values\strings.xml file.

Use %% instead of % and then clean and build the project.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  Made the change still get the error.  I seem to have a problem with widget_word.xml as well it is x'd in eclipse. Could I have the wrong strings.xml or widget_word.xml?

Comment: Was facing same error with 2.2 sample of SearchableDictionary. Your suggestion fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Change build target from 1.5 or 1.6 to 2.2 (API version 8)

Update res\values\string.xml and replace % with %%

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem.  Adding 1$ & 2$ to specify positions did the trick.  The corrected lines from strings.xml are:

```
<string name="template_user_agent">"%1$s/%2$s (Linux; Android)"</string>
<string name="template_wotd_title">"Wiktionary:Word of the day/%1$s %2$s"</string>
```